Why does my Mac show a disk image named Creedence11M6270.SECUREPKITRUSTSTOREASSETS_SECUREPKITRUSTSTORE_Cryptex after updating the OS?
I noticed after updating Catalina to Sequoia, Disk Utility on my Mac shows a disk image named Creedence11M6270.SECUREPKITRUSTSTOREASSETS_SECUREPKITRUSTSTORE_Cryptex:

It does not take up much space, but the name is not familiar to me and Apple doesn't document this anywhere officially in their support pages.  I don't think the size it occupies is a serious problem for me, but I would like to know if it's legitimate or a sign of an update that was not entirely successful.
here is the output of diskutils list:
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         27.7 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1000.0 GB  disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk1s2, disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     398.3 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 4.5 GB     disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.3 GB     disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.1 GB    disk2s4
   5:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 11.1 GB    disk2s4s1
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 MB     disk2s6

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   +4.2 MB     disk3

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +4.2 MB     disk4
                                 Physical Store disk3
   1:                APFS Volume Creedence11M6270.SEC... 692.2 KB   disk4s1

How can I learn why it exists?

What model is your Mac? I am betting on it being Intel and probably the 2019 iMac.

No, it is not just Intel. See https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/in-disk-utility-suddenly-are-7-disk-images-with-strange-names-they-start-with-creedence-or-revival-and-all-end-with-_cryptex.2443437/ where the OP is using an M3 iMac.

This is likely a normal part of Apple's OS which is clearly undocumented by Apple and possibly your cryptex is in a non-normal state being visible (or you just caught it and now Disk Utility remembers it and all you need to do is eject it, safe boot, and move on).

I have the same on my iMac 2019 Intel CPU updated to macOS 15.0, 15.1, & 15.1.1.  But not on my Apple silicon M3 MacBook Pro.
The relevant lines from diskutil list:
/dev/disk14 (disk image):
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
 0:                                                   +4.2 MB     disk14

/dev/disk15 (synthesized):
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
 0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +4.2 MB     disk15
                               Physical Store disk14
 1:                APFS Volume Creedence11M6270.SEC... 692.2 KB   disk15s1

Cryptexes are used to store cryptographically signed code in addition to that in the macOS system volume. For an extensive discussion of cryptexes see this by Howard Oakley.
There are discussions of this particular cryptex issue on the web, e.g.
Four Creedence Cryptexes on desktop.
This claims to include a fix, but I am not convinced Fix: Disks Called Creedence Cryptex Appear on Mac Desktop.
But there is some suggestion that one (or more) cyptexes are visibly mounted due to interaction with either VPN or A-V software.  I have not investigated this, but likely starts by booting in Safe Mode.

The Creedence cryptex is mounted inside this folder: /System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_PKITrustStore/purpose_auto/6dd55b0d06633a00de6f57ccb910a66a5ba2409a.asset
From the folder names in the path and from its content, the cryptex is holding PKI system root trusts. Without knowing in detail how it is used, this does seem to be a good use of the cryptex methodology in that a) it is signed so can't be tampered with, and b) can be updated by Apple without requiring a macOS update.

The cryptex does not seem to have any direct connection with these items which are part of my $PATH variable::
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:

On my system, the /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap folder is empty!

Thanks, this helps. At lest that thing does not seem to be malware, and as long as it shows up only in the Disk Utility and does not clutter Finder or my Desktop, I can live with it.

@user1934428 I’m curious after reading Howard Oakley’s post more closely if you have this cryptex as part of your path (meaning it’s intentionally mounted and contains something expected to run). From the shell, echo $PATH

@bmike : Indeed, I do, and I am sure that I have never put it into my startup files! I will have to trace my zsh startup to see, at which point they come in: /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin ... It's creepy!

Well, this actually isn’t creepy since it lines up with what we currently know how these cryptex are supposed to work. I would 100% open a support case with Apple. If these are legit, Apple needs to fix the cleanup of cases like yours where a background cryptex should be hidden. Or they need to document publicly why these are OK and how to tell a good cryptex from a potentially malicious one.

@bmike My path also has those locations.  But that is not where the Creedence cryptex is mounted.

@bmike Do you have the Creedence cryptex mounted at /System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_PKITrustStore/purpose_auto/6dd55b0d06633a00de6f57ccb910a66a5ba2409a.asset? If yes, then the mounting is normal and the oddity is limited to visibility in Disk Utility. If no, then the mounting at that mount point is the oddity.

No I do not, I only have access to a few Macs now, but none show this. Also none are MDM managed or have any sort of enterprise management software (VPN that use corporate type setup, anti malware, etc...) Also, I think something is messed up or installed that triggers this in a subset of Macs that show a cryptex. Most Macs should have them show up briefly and then go away when the OS is done with them.

@bmike Thanks!  I did just that a few minutes ago (sent feedback to Apple) as I too have this and so do a number of others; mine being on an iMac 2019 (Intel) with macOS 15.1.1 that to top it off can't mount my previous Time Machine disk in a Sabrent enclosure.  This is how I found the addition issue of the Cryptex mount.
